# Why does using the "AND" operator works with a JOIN, even without a "WHERE" clause

Tags: php, mysql, join, where-clause

Good afternoon, I just noticed something. If I write a mysql query with a JOIN in it, for example:

```
Select Car, Vendor from Cars JOIN Vendor On Vendor.IdCar=Car.IdCar WHERE  Car="Brand"
```

It will return that car that is equal to "Brand".

But I noticed that if I structure the query this way:

```
Select Car, Vendor from Cars JOIN Vendor On Vendor.IdCar=Car.IdCar AND Car="Brand"
```

It will return the same thing as the previous query. Noticed that I used AND instead of WHERE. I also tested in PHP queries it worked. So for example:

```
Select Car, Vendor from Cars JOIN Vendor On Vendor.IdCar=Car.IdCar AND Car=$brand
```

instead of

```
Select Car, Vendor from Cars JOIN Vendor On Vendor.IdCar=Car.IdCar WHERE Car=$brand
```

So the question I'm asking is: Why does the second query work? Is it because JOIN was used, because I was pretty sure that WHERE clause was needed before AND?

Comment: Yes, the AND appends to the join clause

Comment: Interesting question. Probably one that Gordon Linoff could explain; he's quite good at this type of thing and well-versed in SQL.

Comment: because the `AND` is applied to your `ON` clause, not specifically the `JOIN` clause. While it's not exactly the same, it serve a similar purpose here of filtration for the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `WHERE` and `ON` require a (boolean) condition. And a boolean condition can be constructed from boolean terms by combining them with `AND`, `OR` and `NOT`(and possibly `(` and `)` )

- `WHERE`*condition* is an (optional) **clause** in a query
- *table-expression* `JOIN` *table-expression* `ON` *condition* is an **operator** that combines two *table-expression*s, based on the *condition*.

Answer (score 4):

Because a `JOIN` is not restricted to match on primary keys; and even if it was, there are composite keys which require multiple columns to match, so you definitely need `AND` there.

The statement you show is not good style, because it abuses the join clause to emulate what should rather be a where condition; yet, it will work as desired.

The statement could definitely make sense if you were to use an *outer* join. In that case, the boolean expression in the join clause is *not* functionally equivalent to the same boolean expression in the where clause. Hence, depending on what you want to query for with an outer join, you *must* use one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

`join` is short for `inner join`, so you are filtering the join on all conditions in the `on`  clause. This has the same effect as placing the condition in the `where` clause. If you use an `outer join` (left or right), you'd get all records of the table on the left or right side of the join, and `null` values for those records that don't match the condition, while a `where` clause would still only select those records that do match the condition.

Answer (score 0):

It is for readability purpose so you can place the `on` clause in the `where` clause and things will be done correctly:

```
Select Car, Vendor from Cars JOIN Vendor where Vendor.IdCar=Car.IdCar AND Car="Brand";
```

And this is valid also:

```
Select Car, Vendor from Cars, Vendor where Vendor.IdCar=Car.IdCar AND Car="Brand";
```

But it can't do outer join(left join or right join)

Comment: It is generally advised to use the join clause though, most people find it much easier to read. Commas to join is pre 95 (or somewhere around that)!

Comment: @HoneyBadger It is completely true.